# django template includes

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm having an issue with django templates at the moment. I have 3 template files basically:

- Base
- story_list
- story_detail

Story_list and _detail extend Base, and that works perfectly fine. However, list and detail share some code that extend the base template for my sidebar. I'm basically repeating a chunk of code in both templates, and the programmer in me says that's just wrong. There has to be a better way, I'm sure of it. I've tried includes, however I have in the included file:

```
{% block item %}
    content stuff
{% endblock %}
```

for about 3 blocks. The problem is that none of that is being picked up/rendered. If I include the file in a block section that extends base, then it dumps everything properly, but if I don't include it in a block, I get nothing. Is SSI the way to go? I toyed with that, but that didn't seem to work properly either. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm confused. Why not put the sidebar stuff in base itself?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Generally, using `include`s is not the answer with Django templates. Let me answer your question on several fronts.

First, let me address the sidebar.

- **Are nearly all the common pages going to be using that sidebar?** Put it in `Base`. Don't override those sidebar blocks (i.e. don't write them at all in your `Story_*` templates).
- **Is this sidebar unique to the `Story_*` templates?** Make another template called, say, `Story_base` and extend that. This is akin to making an abstract superclass in Java. (Answer was in my head, but wording was mercilessly [ripped off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849463/django-template-includes/849530#849530) from jpwatts.)

Next, let me address template inheritance. Say you have a template named `Story_list` that extends `Base`. At this point, after just putting `{% extends "Base" %}`, `Story_list` *is exactly* `Base`. Anything else you put in `Story_list` is ignored, because the template is already complete. The only thing you can do now is *override* blocks that have been defined in `Base`.

Finally, let me address `include`s. Try to always avoid them. Other templating engines, such as PHP, seem to encourage using `include`s. However, this can lead to less manageable templates in the long run. It's slightly harder to glance at an included snippet and immediately ascertain its place in your template hierarchy. They're also harder to refactor into the template hierarchy, especially if you include them at several levels (once in `Base`, twice in `Story_base`, once in some of the `Story_*`, etc.).

Comment: The sidebar is common to all pages. I currently have them in base, and extend that out in each template. The extension is the exact same code in each child template though. That's what I'm trying to avoid. Can I do that when I have to render to these certain templates? Basically, the sidebar needs certain variables in order to be complete. That's the part I guess I'm not comprehending. Thanks for the explanation and time.

Comment: When you render your child template Story_*, imagine that you are making a copy of Base, replacing all the content in the blocks with the blocks defined in Story_*, and THEN filling in the values of the variables. If your Base has a sidebar with a {{ my_page_name }} variable, and you render Story_list with my_page_name = "STORY_LIST", then you will see "STORY_LIST" in the sidebar.

Comment: Only those who don't ask questions are real idiots :P You're welcome. (Hmm, I better post a question on SO soon...)

Answer (score 6):

If there is common code between the story templates that isn't needed site-wide, I'd create a `story_base` (extending the original `base`) and have my story templates extend that.

Answer (score 0):

You have an [{% include %}](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#include) tag for this.

Comment: Yeah, as noted above, it isn't working how I envisioned it would.

Comment: "If I include the file in a block section that extends base, then it dumps everything properly"  Sounds like it works.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

```
{% include xxx.html %}
```

This tag works.

An alternative way is to use filter. Filter calls a function for rendering, template can be used while rendering.